# Boolean full text search order by relevancy doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, search, boolean, relevance

OK so I've got two queries that I'm testing and they produce exactly the same results, which goes to say that somehow ordering by relevancy doesnt seem to work here:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ads 
           WHERE 
             MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('+".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
             AND status='Active'";

$query2 = "SELECT *, 
             MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('+".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
               AS score 
           FROM ads 
           WHERE status='Active' AND 
             MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('+".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
           ORDER BY score desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you specify the order you want the results to be returned.

```
ORDER BY desc, score DESC;
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to fix the issue, the query returns nothing now